# SOLVED: Shortcode to display Divi project filtered by tag in WP Query loop

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, shortcode

I'm creating a template for a custom post type & I'm trying to add a WP Query loop displaying specific Divi projects filtered by tag. I'm inserting the loop using a shortcode, & I've successfully done so for `'post_type' => 'post'`, but when I use the same query loop for `'post_type' => 'project'` it's not working. What do I need to do differently for Divi projects? Here is my code that is working for displaying posts filtered by tag, with the `'post_type'` modified to `'project'`:

```
add_action('init', function(){
  add_shortcode('member_project_shortcode', function(){

  global $post;

    // Define output var
    $output = '';

    // Define query
    $tag = sanitize_title_with_dashes(get_the_title());
    $query_args = array(
      'post_type' => 'project',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'order' => 'DESC',
      'orderby' => 'date',
      'posts_per_page' => '3',
      'tag' => $tag
    );

    // Query posts
    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

    // Add content if we found posts via our query
    if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {

        // Open div wrapper around loop
        $output .= '<div class="grid-container">';

        // Loop through posts
        while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {

            // Sets up post data so you can use functions like get_the_title(), get_permalink(), etc
            $custom_query->the_post();

            // This is the output for your entry so what you want to do for each post.
            $output .= '<div>' . get_the_title() . '</div>';

        }

        // Close div wrapper around loop & grid-container
        $output .= '</div>';

        // Restore data
        wp_reset_postdata();

    }

    // Return your shortcode output
    return $output;

  });
});
```

Comment: have you asked this in a Divi community? Questions about 3rd party plugins/themes and their features are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope

Comment: @TomJNowell I've asked in the Divi Facebook group, but I'm not sure if my issue is totally related to Divi. Would you expect the code above to work for a custom post type had I created the 'project' custom post type myself?

Comment: Is the problem that you're not getting any results from the query? I'd check if the Divi project uses the same tags or a different taxonomy. Does it work if you take out the tag restriction? Is it definitely just called "project"? I'd also try and find the exact SQL it's trying (e.g. Query Monitor) and play with that in whatever database tool you use until you get results.

Comment: @Rup it's displaying my projects, but only if I remove "'tag' => $tag". Do you know how I can print my arguments to the page using $output notation? When I try 'echo $tag' I get a critical error..

Comment: Huh, echo ought to work. You could try `error_log($tag);` instead which writes to your server error log, PHP error log or WordPress debug log depending on how you're set up. It should just be the sanitised title with dashes though, as you're using for posts. I'd also pick one of the projects and look what tags it has, and what taxonomies those tags are in, to make sure they line up with what you're searching for anyway.

Comment: if your CPT was named `project` then you would put `project`, the only concern would be if you get nothing because there is nothing that matches, e.g. the `tag` parameter. As for divi projects though, you'd need to know what the name of the post type divi registered was, as well as any filters it added, which means you're now knee deep in Divi docs and code. Are you sure the post type even supports post tags? And that they didn't register a custom taxonomy that's also got the name tags? E.g. Project Tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: I looked through Divi's functions.php & saw that the term for the project tags is `'project_tag'`, so when I amended my $query args it now works!
Thank you very much to everyone who responded :)

```
$query_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'project',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'posts_per_page' => '3',
  'project_tag' => $tag
);
```